# How to draw neat polygons around scatterplot regions in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, scatterplot

**How do I add a neat polygon around a group of points on a scatterplot?** I am using ggplot2 but am disappointed with the results of `geom_polygon`.

The dataset is [over there](http://pastebin.com/emD71JT5), as a tab-delimited text file. The graph below shows two measures of attitudes towards health and unemployment in a bunch of countries:

[image: scatterplot with density2d]

I would like to switch from `geom_density2d` to the less fancy but empirically more correct `geom_polygon`. The result on unsorted data is unhelpful:

[image]

How do I draw 'neat' polygons that behave as contour paths around the min-max y-x values? I tried sorting the data to no avail.

**Code:**

```
print(fig2 <- ggplot(d, aes(man, eff, colour=issue, fill=issue)) + 
geom_point() + geom_density2d(alpha=.5) + labs(x = "Efficiency", y = "Mandate"))
```

The `d` object is obtained with [this CSV file](http://pastebin.com/emD71JT5).

**Solution:**

Thanks to **Wayne**, **Andy W** and others for their pointers! The data, code and graphs have been [posted to GitHub](https://github.com/briatte/moralecon). The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: The term you might be looking for is the *convex hull* of the points (or potentially the alpha hull). You should be able to find an R function to calculate these and then be able to add them as layers to the plot.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the correct terminology! I have failed to use `?chull` with `ggplot2` so far. I am not sure that I am coding it right, and hope that someone has done it already.

Comment: Could you add your R code to question?

Comment: One thing to note: what you're displaying are the maxima, which may be "outliers". I believe the R package `alphahull` works similar to finding the convex hull, but allows you to adjust it inwards/outwards to try to do something like confidence intervals.

Comment: @Wayne, an alpha hull is not a confidence interval (in any way imaginable). See [this gis.se question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/1200/751) for a brief description and some references of what an alpha hull is. Perhaps your thinking of bivariate confidence ellipses, or maybe even bagplots (bi-variate boxplots for identifying outliers).

Comment: Looking at the final graph using an alpha hull is unlikely to change the general interpretation, although all of the polygons will be slightly smaller and unemployment will be more obviously seperated from health and pensions. I'm less familiar with the bivariate confidence ellipses in such a situation, but I suspect they would look similar/have similar interpretation to the original contour plot posted (although constrained to be more regular ellipses in all applications I have seen).

Comment: @Andy W: Ah, okay. I've used the package once and it was my impression that it could shrink the convex-like hull in a way that might avoid outliers. As you point out, bivariate confidence ellipses would probably be what Fr. would actually want. The overall issue is that a convex hull will happily include outliers no matter how extreme and could thus be misleading if not dealt with in some way (Perhaps a pre-processing step, perhaps in the graphing step.)

Comment: @Wayne, The alpha hull would include any outlier as well. It shrinks the overall area of the polygon but actually makes the outer ring of the polygon more detailed and includes *more* points as vertex's in the polygon ring. All of the same polygon vertex's for the convex hull would be included in the alpha hull.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With some googling I came across the website of Gota Morota who has an example of doing this already on [her website](http://www.ansci.wisc.edu/morota/R/ggplot2/ggplot2.html#section0010). Below is that example extended to your data.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
work <- "E:\\Forum_Post_Stuff\\convex_hull_ggplot2"
setwd(work)

#note you have some missing data
mydata <- read.table(file = "emD71JT5.txt",header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
nomissing <- na.omit(mydata) #chull function does not work with missing data

#getting the convex hull of each unique point set
df <- nomissing
find_hull <- function(df) df[chull(df$eff, df$man), ]
hulls <- ddply(df, "issue", find_hull)

plot <- ggplot(data = nomissing, aes(x = eff, y = man, colour=issue, fill = issue)) +
geom_point() + 
geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.5) +
labs(x = "Efficiency", y = "Mandate")
plot
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll revise the code accordingly. Unfortunately, your image file does not seem to load here, but the code is there.

Comment: @Fr. , What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @AndyW Unfortunately, the code does not support missing values, and I did not find a way to tweak it to do so.

Comment: @Fr., How exactly do you want missing data values to be handled besides eliminating those observations? Any reasonable imputation technique would result in the points being *inside* the convex hulls of the non-missing observations.

Comment: @AndyW I mean that the `NA` kill the `chull` function. I would expect it to just ignore it, but it fails at doing so and I did not find a way to use `na.omit()` to make it work. I'm sure it's possible, I just don't have the hackery skills to go beyond the previous solution.

Comment: @Fr. It still isn't clear how the code I provided doesn't generalize to your use case (i.e. solve the problem with missing data). Feel free to ask for clarification if there is anything you do not understand. I dealt with the missing data by taking the original data frame (what I named `mydata`) and made a new dataframe (named `nomissing`) by deleting caseslistwise with missing information. I then made a custom function to return the convex hull for each of the factors within the "issue" variable. Then it is as simple as plotting the scatterplot and adding a layer of the convex hulls.

Comment: @AndyW I just succeeded at shifting to your code! I'll have the vanity to post that on GitHub, as I'm learning to use that too.

Comment: Edit done to original post. Thanks again for taking the time to help me. The mistake was mine, I was passing option to `geom_point` instead of `ggplot`, which was causing the polygons to be empty.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your problem, you're looking for the convex hull of `health` and of `unemployment`. There are probably several packages to do this in R, one of which is package `geometry`. I'd imagine that the points are sorted in order around the perimeter, but you'd have to check that.

EDIT: Here's an example, which doesn't use `ggplot`, but I hope it's useful. The example in the `chull` documentation seems to be wrong, which might be throwing you off:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(2000), ncol = 2)
X.chull <- chull (X)
X.chull <- c(X.chull, X.chull[1])
plot (X)
lines (X[X.chull,])
```

EDIT 2: OK, here is something using ggplot2. We turn `X` into a `data.frame` with variables `x` and `y`. Then:

```
library(ggplot2)
X <- as.data.frame(X)
hull <- chull(X)
hull <- c(hull, hull[1])
ggplot(X, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(data=X[hull,], fill="red") + geom_point()
```

Note that the `geom_point` is using the data (`X`) and aes from the ggplot, while I'm overriding it in the `geom_polygon`.

To get it fully, you'd need to put the x and y for the hull for both issues into `bar`, using a third column `issue` to differentiate them.

Comment: Correct about the convex hull. I have tried to use `chull` to generate the convex hull but failed to use the results with `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Fr.: I've done a quick edit of my answer. See if that puts you on the right track.

Comment: I can see how it works on its own, but I wonder how to obtain that last line with `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Fr.: OK, how about now?

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I had to add `na.omit` to get rid of NA that stop `chull` from working. Thanks again.

Comment: I modified your `ggplot` example to make it run on the same data as the base graphics example

Answer (score 9):

As of this afternoon, I've wrapped the `chull` function inside an R package as a `geom_convexhull` function.

Once the package is loaded, it can be used as any other geom, in your case it should be something like :

```
ggplot(d, aes(man, eff, colour=issue, fill=issue)) + 
  geom_convexhull(alpha=.5) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(x = "Efficiency", y = "Mandate"))
```

The package is available on github : https://github.com/cmartin/ggConvexHull

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I was getting frustrated from undesired output when trying to apply `chull` across a grouping factor until I found this.